# Add safeguards to the account deletion process

Tags: feature-request, user-experience, deleted-users

I was trying to delete some SE profiles I didn't use that were associated with my account, and, while figuring out the process of doing this for a specific SE site, I accidentally made a request to delete my SO account instead. I stupidly assumed that the profile URL field on the [contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) was automatically filled from the specific SE site I navigated: I wouldn't expect it to auto-fill with the profile URL of some other SE site.

Of course it's my fault for not reading more carefully and checking the information, and I feel stupid and quite sad that the account I've had for years will be deleted (I've sent an email to the SO team that I hope reaches them before they process the deletion request).

In posting this suggestion I wish to avoid anybody else this sad fate. From a UX point of view it would make sense to add more safeguards to the deletion process in the [contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact):

1. **Don't auto-fill the profile URL:** When the user has to supply the URL manually, there is less chance of them misunderstanding the form and deleting their SO account. In being auto-filled, it can also give the false sense that the form needs a link to your profile (of any SE site) and you should specify which SE sites you want deleted in the "Please describe your problem" field.
2. **Require email confirmation:** For such a devastating action, it's too easy for a mischievous person, who illegally got access to your account, to irreversibly delete your precious profile. For example, if you accidentally left a PC with your account logged in, or they got your login credentials in some other illegal way. All it takes is a few clicks on a simple form.

Comment: FYI, every site has a separate contact form. If you use [the Super User one](http://superuser.com/contact) for example it would autofill your SU profile instead.

Comment: It also takes several days, at least, for the deletion to happen.  It's trivially easy to stop during that entire time.  You can only instantaneously delete an account that has no activity at all, in which case, you can trivially re-create the account with nothing being lost.

Comment: @approxiblue Hmm I really hope you're right. I navigated back to the form to check before posting this suggestion, and it was the SO link. The email I got said "You recently sent a request to have your Meta Stack Exchange profile removed." with no other information about the profile. I'm hoping this means it's the Meta profile, not the SO profile that's being deleted!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's **not possible** to schedule a profile for deletion from another site than the one you're currently on. Only the profile URL for the current site will even get accepted by that form. You can't submit anything else. If you pasted a URL for a different site into the box, it would tell you the link is invalid.

We already do have a safeguard if your profile is over 1,000 reputation. It gets kicked to us for manual review, and we send an email to the user. They're required to perform some actions and then respond to verify the request. We are planning to get rid of the "us" part there when we revamp the entire deletion system (hopefully). But we also plan to have any new automated deletion tool automatically fire off an email to the address on file for the account to warn them about the deletion. But, the new system may still be a ways off.

In your particular case, you sent in a request from Meta Stack Exchange, so your [profile there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/254905/spaghetti) would be deleted should you follow through. It would not affect your Stack Overflow profile.

Also of note: your profile is not scheduled for deletion simply by using the form. Eventually, a deletion link will land in your inbox. You must click that link in order for it be scheduled. Once it's clicked, you have 24 hours to change your mind.

Comment: That is really great to hear! Phew! The deletion link you mention at the end of your answer: does everyone receive that or only users above 1k rep? Otherwise, it seems that those below the threshold have no way to reverse the request once the form is submitted. About the URL being only accepted from the contact form's site: this is not a perfect safeguard, because when lost in a sea of tabs you could click the link to the contact form from an answer on another SE site, like I did. If the URL must be entered manually, there is no ambiguity.

Comment: @Spaghetti Only users under 1k can receive the link. Users above 1k have to do manual things and respond to us. It's also very easy to reverse. You can either ignore the link and let it expire and become useless, or there's also a cancel button if it's been clicked and you changed your mind within the 24 hour countdown.

Comment: I see. I was panicked because the confirmation dialogue on the contact form said otherwise. It said "User deletion is irreversible!" when you pick the "I need to delete my profile" option. Also, the email I received immediately after had no confirmation/cancel links, only that the "request has been received, and we will respond with help ASAP." So you can see how I thought my account was to be imminently deleted. (I have less than 1,000 rep on my MSO account.)

Comment: @Spaghetti Hopefully the new deletion system we've proposed will alleviate a lot of this. It's designed to drastically simplify this process and make it more clear what will happen. The deletion link system will be entirely eradicated, in favor of immediately scheduling for deletion and beginning the 24-hour countdown - which would make it immediately apparent that it can be easily cancelled. But, everyone here knows how implementation timelines go.

Comment: @animuson So, in 6-8 weeks?

Comment: ...How would your MSO account be deleted without affecting your main site account? I thought meta accounts were permanently associated with your main site account since they share rep counts. Would it just remove your badges and disassociate all your activity?

Comment: @skrrgwasme Meta Stack Exchange is not the same as Meta Stack Overflow. Users cannot delete only their per-site Meta profile by themselves, but the network Meta is set up as a normal "main" Q&A site.

Comment: @animuson D'oh! I just accidentally read MSE as MSO. That was my bad for reading too fast. Thanks for the clarification, it all makes sense now.